# Asp.Net C# Mutliptle submit button not working with multiple asp.net panel default button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need some help about Asp.Net C# Mutliptle submit button not working with multiple asp.net panel default button.

I have used two asp.net panel with default button and textbox required field validator.

when I click the first panel button automatically both panel textbox required filed validator required.

when I click the second button automatically both panel textbox required field validator required.

remember that all working code inside master page.

Comment: ***remember that all working code inside master page*** where is that code? Feel free to post your code here

Comment: you need to use validationgroup on buttons and textbox, and group them to mulitple submit buttons. If you are not adding it, each submit will trigger all required fields on the page.